# Kendo UI Grid Header

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem with the size header grid misconfiguration, anyone can help me with that?.

The Yellow color highlight columns can see the blank space between the top and columns.

I can't find the css configuration.

[image: Header and Row Misconfiguration]

Comment: Are you defining any CSS style for `tr` (HTML table row). Seems that you are forcing some height. Could you try reproducing it in JSFiddle / JSBin so we can take a look into it?

Comment: This header, is misconfiguration with the rest of the grid, identify the columns with the color yellow respect the header, this have a separation with the top, how i fix that? Thanks for the reply and sorry for my english...

Comment: The problem is not just in the headers. I see the same separation on top of the first row. That's why I'm asking about CSS styles.

Comment: I try fix it trought CSS style, but i don't find the topic of that

Comment: You are most likely overriding the default `tr` element with _your own_ css. Inspect the element, see where that additional height is coming from, remove that from _your_ css.

Comment: Thers are two possiblity for this issue. Either you have changed the grid css-class or some other Global css-class applied in this TR.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i found the css-class override my table, but i change the attribute and my borwser don't apply the change, why? I updated with F5, restart the machine, open with Adobe Dreamweaver the css file and the change is correct, but don't apply the change of the browser

Comment: @kingve try clearing  your browser cache

Comment: Ready, thanks for the tips @gitsitgo; thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This table (grid) has override by another css-class in other file; running my app with page inspector and find my issue.

Thanks to all for the help